# Cloudflare & Heroku (DNS): An A, AAAA or CNAME record was not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns, cloudflare

I have tried to apply free SSL service provided by Cloudflare to my Heroku app.

Although I registered my domain about 4 days ago, it doesn't work.

When I try to access my domain (example.com and www.example.com) with Chrome, `This site can’t be reached example.com’s server DNS address could not be found.` is displayed.

The following messages are displayed when I check the Cloudflare site.

```
An A, AAAA or CNAME record was not found for the www subdomain. The www.example.com subdomain will not resolve.
An A, AAAA or CNAME record was not found pointing to the root domain. The example.com domain will not resolve.
An MX record was not found for your root domain. An MX record is required for mail to reach @example.com addresses.
```

I could access my domain `www.example.com` before using Cloudflare.
How can I use my domain with SSL?

My setting summary in Cloudflare is as follows;

```
Security Level: Medium
SSL: Full
```

I get my domain and set up as below on the home page which I get my domain.

```
sub domain: www
type: CNAME
content: floating-fortress-999999.herokuapp.com

name server1: foo.ns.cloudflare.com
name server2: bar.ns.cloudflare.com
```

When I try to `dig` command, the followings are displayed.

```
$ dig example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 301
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                   IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.            9999    IN      SOA     foo.ns.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2021450999 10000 0000 999900 9900

;; Query time: 53 msec
;; SERVER: 999.99.9.9#53(999.99.9.9)
;; WHEN: Fri May 13 21:11:54 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 101
```

When I try to `dig` command with `ns`, the followings are dispaleyed.

```
$ dig example.com ns

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> example.com ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9999
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                   IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            99999   IN      NS      bar.ns.cloudflare.com.
example.com.            99999   IN      NS      foo.ns.cloudflare.com.

;; Query time: 173 msec
;; SERVER: 999.99.9.9#53(999.99.9.9)
;; WHEN: Fri May 13 21:12:53 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96
```

It would be appreciated if you give me any suggestion.

Comment: heroku already provide you SSL, No?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @YOU. SSL works in heroku sub domain such as `floating-fortress-999999.herokuapp.com`. But I'd like to apply SSL to my domain.

Comment: oh, i see, so it does not work out of the box.

Comment: btw, you followed this article about heroku, right? https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-CloudFlare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @YOU. It works when I try to add a domain by running the following command: `heroku domain:add www.example.com`.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue You can answer your own question and close this, since it's a solved problem now. I just went through entire question to see if I can help.